# MS BotFramework Data Saving, BotState

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

Below is the entire code block, basically the formflow, I'm trying save the data into botState.

```
public class ProfileForm
{
    // these are the fields that will hold the data
    // we will gather with the form
    [Prompt("What is your first name? {||}")]
    public string FirstName;

    [Prompt("What is your last name? {||}")]
    public string LastName;

    [Prompt("What is your gender? {||}")]
    public Gender Gender;

    // This method 'builds' the form 
    // This method will be called by code we will place
    // in the MakeRootDialog method of the MessagesControlller.cs file

    public static IForm<ProfileForm> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<ProfileForm>()

                .Message("Please complete your profile!")
                .OnCompletion(async (context, profileForm) =>

                {
                    BotData bt = new BotData();

                    await context.PostAsync("Your profile is complete.\n\n"+profileForm.FirstName+profileForm.LastName+profileForm.Gender);

                    SessionInfo.botUserData.SetProperty<bool>("ProfileComplete", true);
                    SessionInfo.botUserData.SetProperty<string>("FirstName", profileForm.FirstName);
                    SessionInfo.botUserData.SetProperty<string>("LastName", profileForm.LastName);
                    SessionInfo.botUserData.SetProperty<string>("Gender", profileForm.Gender==Gender.Male? "Male" :"Female");

                    await context.PostAsync("Before Saving");

                    await SessionInfo.userStateClient.BotState.SetPrivateConversationDataWithHttpMessagesAsync(
                        SessionInfo.ChannelID, SessionInfo.ConversationID, SessionInfo.FromID, SessionInfo.botUserData);
                    // Tell the user that the form is complete
                    await context.PostAsync("Your profile is complete.");

                })
                .Build();
    }
}
// This enum provides the possible values for the 
// Gender property in the ProfileForm class
// Notice we start the options at 1 
[Serializable]

public enum Gender

{

    Male = 1, Female = 2

};
```

I've got the following error at line `SetPrivateConversationDataWithHttpMessagesAsync()` method call, Please help.

---

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.FormDialog1.<MessageReceived>d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume1.d4.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d19.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame1.&lt;Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop&lt;C&gt;-PollAsync&gt;d__9.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d16.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter&lt;T&gt;.GetResult()    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.FromDialog1.<ResumeAsync>d3.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume1.&lt;Rest&gt;d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d19.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.-PollAsync>d9.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog1.<ResumeAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume1.d4.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d19.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame1.&lt;Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop&lt;C&gt;-PollAsync&gt;d__9.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d16.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IDialogStack-PollAsync>d20.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d22`1.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.d31.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringDialogTask1.d3`1.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d31.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.&lt;Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync&gt;d__31.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializingDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d4`1.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.d21.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LocalizedDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUserTask.d5`1.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUserTask.d51.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LogPostToBot.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
>   — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   — at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.d4.MoveNext() —
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.d2.MoveNext() —
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task
>   task) at LUISBotAppTesting.MessagesController.d__1.MoveNext()

Comment: really hard to know what's going on here if you don't publish the entire code involved.

Comment: I've updated the entire code block, basically it is inside a form flow, I'm trying to save the data in bot state. In more detail, I'm using this code from Facebook Messenger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit hard to understand the problem, but I would like to mention, that function `botUserData.SetProperty<>()` doesn't save property it just edits property of current object. You should use `BotState.SetUserData()` and pass him the object to save it.
Here is a working example of saving bot state:

```
public static bool saveData(Activity activity, string key, string value)
{
    StateClient stateClient = activity.GetStateClient();
    BotData userData = stateClient.BotState.GetUserData(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);
    userData.SetProperty<string>(key, value);
    BotData updateResponse = stateClient.BotState.SetUserData(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);
    return value == updateResponse.GetProperty<string>(key);
}
```